# Exchange server 2010 stopped receiving incoming emails

Tags: exchange-2010, email

We have an Exchange Server 2010 V 14.01.438 running on Window Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, which stopped receiving incoming emails about three hours ago, however everything we checked appears to be in order.

Items we checked so far:

- Internal emails are working fine
- Outgoing emails are working, a 10-14 second delay more than usual is felt
- Nothing in incoming queues on management console
- New incoming messages do not appear be go through the ORF (so we thought perhaps an incoming port block)
- SMTP test from MXToolBox passed
- Server is not blacklisted (MXToolBox)
- Telnet to server's port 25 works fine, also from outside the network
- Senders (we used gmail for testing) are not receiving any error messages
- We tried restarting the information store service and the server itself
- Additional info: No update / work was done on the server in the past week. The drive which is running Exchange has 8.5GB free. Server does not appear to be under any loads

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Are you certain that your MX record is correct and resolving to the A record of the host properly?

Comment: Hi @EvanAnderson and thank you for your reply. Yes we are sure, we checked this using the mxtoolbox tools. The address was correctly resolved and pointed to the correct server.

Comment: It'd be useful if you could give me an address at the domain to test sending to, and then I can see what appears in the mail logs.

Comment: Also, 8.5GB free out of what? If it's a large volume, that might be low enough to stop Exchange functioning normally on it's default thresholds - see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd146168.aspx

Comment: Hi @Phil, thank you. Its 8.5 out of 365GB, so abit over 2%. trying to empty up some space now and see if this helps.

Comment: 8.5GB free of 365GB? How big are your mailbox databases? It sounds suspiciously like you're not flushing the transaction logs upon backup. How much in the way of transaction logs are there? Also, you're definitely in a back pressure situation. The server is probably rejecting all inbound external email. Free up some disk space and see if it starts working normally. Have a read of this: http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/exchange-server-2010/management-administration/back-pressure-exchange-2010-part1.html

Comment: Have you found anything in the event logs? Backpressure events will be noted there IIRC, and in the SMTP Transport logs (on the filesystem) as well.

Comment: @joeqwerty, you are right. once we found out the space issue we tracked it down to a backup issue where the logs weren't flushed. currently cleaning 200gb of logs, if this fixes the incoming email issue than we found the solution. will update soon. thanks every for the help

Comment: umm... how are you clearing out the log files? The proper way would be to actually run the backup. Worse case would be to turn on circular logging. Under NO circumstance should you just be deleting log files manually.

Comment: @Phil & Joeqwerty, you were both right. the small amount of space was indeed the cause of the issue & it itself was caused by a backup issue where the logs weren't flushed. Fixed the backup issue which fixed the space issue which fixed the email issue. Thank you all for your assistance. Please make an answer out of it so i can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exchange server enters back pressure mode and refuses external mail when available disk space drops to around 2%.

If there is no obvious reason for your server to be running out of space, check that your backups are running properly as otherwise your exchange transaction logs will eventually fill your disk.